# Difference between these two methods of downloading linux source code

Tags: 12.04, source-code

System info:

```
root@zaidi:/home/uzair# uname -a
Linux zaidi 3.11.0-26-generic #45~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 04:04:35 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

I am trying to write a simple device driver. For that I need to download the source code of the kernel I am running (right?)

I found following two methods:

```
apt-get install linux-source-$(uname -r)


apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

What is the difference between these two commands? Which one is actually required for building the driver. I have a make file like this:

```
# Makefile – makefile of our first driver
# if KERNELRELEASE is defined, we've been invoked from the
# kernel build system and can use its language.
ifneq (${KERNELRELEASE},)
    obj-m := ofd.o
# Otherwise we were called directly from the command line.
# Invoke the kernel build system.
else
    KERNEL_SOURCE := /usr/src/linux
    PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
    ${MAKE} -C ${KERNEL_SOURCE} SUBDIRS=${PWD} modules
clean:
    ${MAKE} -C ${KERNEL_SOURCE} SUBDIRS=${PWD} clean
endif
```

I would like to have the source code in `/usr/src/linux`

Answer (score 1):

**Difference between installation process by `apt-get install` & by `apt-get source`:**

1. `sudo apt-get install <package>`installs packages with their dependencies from repositories and cached files are found at `/var/cache/apt/archives` in `.deb` extension.
2. `sudo apt-get source <package>` will download source files in current directory.

**Now take look at how to build & install package from downloaded source files** (from repository):

- First install build-dependencies by command : `sudo apt-get build-dep <package>`
- Then download source package by command : `sudo apt-get source <package>`
- Then navigate to directory containing source by `cd` and use `dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -b` to get binaries, `dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -S` for a source package without using sudo.
- It get/build `.deb` files which can be installed by `dpkg -i <file-name>.deb`

---

But if `<package>` is directly available to install from repositories then it is recommended to install packages by following command

```
sudo apt-get install <package>
```

---

For compiling package from source code visit :[**community help**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo)

Answer (score 0):

You should only need the appropriate `linux-headers` package:

```
apt-cache show linux-source-3.13.0
Package: linux-source-3.13.0
...
Description-en: Linux kernel source for version 3.13.0 with Ubuntu patches
This package provides the source code for the Linux kernel version
3.13.0.
 .
This package is mainly meant for other packages to use, in order to build
custom flavours.
.
If you wish to use this package to create a custom Linux kernel, then it
is suggested that you investigate the package kernel-package, which has
been designed to ease the task of creating kernel image packages.
.
If you are simply trying to build third-party modules for your kernel,
you do not want this package. Install the appropriate linux-headers
package instead.
```

Do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: But in the makefile I have to give the path of the source, so?

Comment: @gpuguy The headers package installs files in /usr/src. Once installed, do `dpkg -L linux-headers-$(uname -r)` to check.